# "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"occured after compile c program to mips binary file

Tags: c, gcc, mips

The details of warnings, binary file and system arch are as followed. The c program contains a main and  a simple addation function. No external files to be included.

```
zfq@inginging:~/study/sandbox$ mips64-linux-gnuabi64-gcc sandbox.c
zfq@inginging:~/study/sandbox$ ls
a.out  sandbox.c  sandbox.h  sandbox.s
zfq@inginging:~/study/sandbox$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS64 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld.so.1, BuildID[sha1]=a16c9c7aba78aa5adcf89b053bdd3c58a7cbe330, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
zfq@inginging:~/study/sandbox$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.4.0-65-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-048) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021
zfq@inginging:~/study/sandbox$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The binary files still  have format error even the system is x86_64 architecture  and the elf file is also 64bit. Has anyone ever encountered with such a problem?

Comment: Your host is amd64 (intel x64), the binary is MIPS64, that's a completely different CPU with different instructions. It is not runnable on your CPU.

Comment: Cross compilation basically means "I want this compiled program to run on some other architecture". Well, run it on that other architecture then! :) I mean: you took the trouble of bothering with cross-compilation, presumably for a reason? It may be also that you're using a pre-configured environment and simply managed to pick up the wrong compiler for the job: perhaps just using plain `gcc` would do what you want instead of choosing the one for a MIPS target.

Answer (score 3):

If you cross-compile, you are telling: Take this source code and translate it to machine-readable format *not for this computer* but for some other computer/architecture/system.

Therefore a file translated for MIPS can't run on amd64 as these are quite different architecures with completely different instructions.

Try to run in at appropriate architecture - in your case a MIPS64 GNU/Linux computer

Or simly use a native gcc or other cc to produce a binary for the system you are using to compile.